# Wildcarding in SQL with similar wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I have 3 categories:

1. Happy
2. Sad
3. Happy + Sad

```
Id  Code
 1  03FJ
 1  03JO
 3  03PR
 4  03OY
 4  036X
 4. 03JX
```

When the code is like '%03J' but doesn't have any other '%03' values then it is happy.
When the code is like '%03' but doesn't have any '%03J' values then it is sad.
When the code is like '%03' and has other '%03J' values then it is happy + sad

The intended output of above would be

```
Id Emotion
1  Happy
3  Sad
4. Happy + Sad
```

How can I do this? I'm not sure how to capture this when the wildcard are essentially almost the same.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  The most recent versions of SQL Server support `concat_ws()`:

```
select id,
       concat_ws(' + ',
                 (case when sum(case when code like '%03%J%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                       then 'Happy'
                  end),
                 (case when sum(case when code not like '%03%J%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                       then 'Sad'
                  end)
                 ) as emotion
from t
group by id;
```

You can do something similar in older versions of SQL Server using `case` expressions or other methods.